# How to make expandable tree in d3.js vertical?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement an expandable and collapsible tree using d3.js.
But it seems like not working.

Can someone suggest how to fix this?

I mean I'm not being able to expand and toggle it like [this demo](https://codepen.io/augbog/pen/LEXZKK?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=08421bdb6ffbe500455fb987dd5b87f62684d3af-1605511760-0-AZFiQt7LmH9KvUnT-JBLVTun8wED9XKr-6AlJ5AonHc7KGIlZUvj9rHtE0GMYkicsg8kpi4espXenprvzaY6jdgEvKNbLM4EDdTal9--lGa6mGh4Hxy3r6qRkLO7hbPnUGrpfSjeWCLk6Ip9zTq4Hcnif8NOV8s60v8kpIW5mTINIBf0dq43mH1lBqaLuqmGnk3qx16jbzHgZXtgD8YuEKJ4EqrXZMy3zwKUH7lpjJd53FNXZ6o90WyCFVu6XgIwJVeOSsnQm9Q7ZXZAhBuAJSwbFKiY0qe9dL0pkfgCXLHFLr7ajtq1ztplw59w2ciUdi5cGNzJ2XLK9_qojFTckh9ar6AQBUB6-Eb-WKagWm5_).

Following is my implementation in vue.js:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var treeData = {
      name: "Top Level",
      children: [{
          name: "Level 2: A",
          children: [{
              name: "Son of A",
            },
            {
              name: "Daughter of A",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "Level 2: B",
        },
      ],
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90,
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("#tree-graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    //root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }
    }

    function update(source) {
      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(e, d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate
        .select("circle.node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr("cursor", "pointer");

      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link
        .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0,
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        });

      link
        .enter()
        .insert("text", "g")
        .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .attr("fill", "Orange")
        .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return (
            "translate(" +
            (d.parent.y + d.x) / 2 +
            "," +
            (d.parent.x + d.y) / 2 +
            ")"
          );
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent);
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y,
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {
        let path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
    C ${(s.y + d.x) / 2} ${s.x},
      ${(s.y + d.x) / 2} ${d.x},
      ${d.x} ${d.y}`;

        return path;
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(e, d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="tree-graph"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: The fills you can solve with `fill: none` on the paths

Comment: Ok. No worries.! What about the vertical expansion/collapse of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

All I did was flip the coordinates in the `diagonal` function from

```
function diagonal(s, d) {
  let path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
    C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
      ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
      ${d.y} ${d.x}`;
  return path;
}
```

to

```
function diagonal(s, d) {
  let path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
    C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
      ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
      ${d.x} ${d.y}`;
  return path;
}
```

Now, the links come out of the side. That is because the example uses the average `x` of the source `s` and destination `d`. To make the links come out of and go into the top and bottom of the nodes, use the following instead:

```js
function diagonal(s, d) {
  let path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
    C ${s.x} ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},
      ${d.x} ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},
      ${d.x} ${d.y}`;
  return path;
}
```

And for the labels, you changed `(d.parent.y + d.y) / 2` to `(d.parent.y + d.x) / 2`, but you also need to change which coordinate you take from the parent.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var treeData = {
      name: "Top Level",
      children: [{
          name: "Level 2: A",
          children: [{
              name: "Son of A",
            },
            {
              name: "Daughter of A",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "Level 2: B",
        },
      ],
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90,
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("#tree-graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([width, height]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }
    }

    function update(source) {
      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(e, d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate
        .select("circle.node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr("cursor", "pointer");

      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link
        .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0,
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        });

      link
        .enter()
        .insert("text", "g")
        .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .attr("fill", "Orange")
        .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return (
            "translate(" +
            (d.parent.x + d.x) / 2 +
            "," +
            (d.parent.y + d.y) / 2 +
            ")"
          );
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent);
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y,
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {
        let path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
    C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
      ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
      ${d.x} ${d.y}`;

        return path;
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(e, d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="tree-graph"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea. But still if I click on top level. node the children are collapsing to a different direction

Comment: When nodes collapse, it's because they are removed. They are described in `node.exit()`. You missed an `d.x` and `d.y` there, so they collapsed to the wrong direction. Do you understand `enter()` and `exit()`? If not, read [this article](https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function) for more information

Comment: Ruben, One more help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878093/how-to-create-zoomable-treemap-in-d3-js-vue